# How can I create my own OS by customizing Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, package-management, iso

I tried customizing by using different customization tools and by removing different packages at different trials, but none of it worked properly!

The tools that I tried are `Cubic`, `PinguyBuilder`, `optimizer`, `UCK`, `OS Builder`.

What I want to do is to remove all packages given by Ubuntu and make a clean ISO image and what I tried is removed some packages like `libreoffice` related packages, `firefox` and then I generated an ISO image.

After that I installed it in Virtual-Machine but, it's not installing properly (sometimes saying installer crashed when `libreOffice` packages removed, sometimes blank-screen is appearing when any other packages removed, sometimes not even generating ISO).

is there any need of modifying some predefined files after removing/deleting some packages?

How can I create/generate that clean ISO image by removing all unwanted packages provided by Ubuntu?

Comment: If this is all the customisation you need, you could probably just use the Ubuntu server distribution

Comment: I would suggest switching to arch linux if you want better customization. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Linux

Comment: agree with @SebastianStark The server is a clean version. Also: nothing beats the manual method: you learn a LOT about the inner workings.

Comment: @justinbenge thanks for Arch_Linux, i'll have a look into it. 

@SebastianStark can you share any helpful documentation/links/material for `Ubuntu Server Distribution`, will be very helpful for me.

:)

Comment: "None of it worked" might mean that you are doing it wrong. A couple of those work very well. Without details about exactly how each failed, it's impossible to give you specific advice.

Comment: @user535733 in my post i mentioned "what i tried is", what else can i mention/explain to make it clear?

Comment: Complete error messages help. Full details of *exactly* what you tried, and exactly how it failed. We are not psychic.

Answer (score 5):

One among other, **Cubic**, acronym for **C**ustom **Ub**untu **I**SO **C**reator, is a GUI application to create a customized bootable Ubuntu Live CD (ISO) image.

> Cubic (Custom Ubuntu ISO Creator) is a GUI wizard to create a
>   customized bootable Ubuntu Live CD (ISO) image. Cubic features an
>   integrated command line chroot environment to make the customizations
>   and permits effortless navigation, backward and forward, through the
>   ISO generation steps. You can create new customization projects or
>   modify existing projects. Important parameters are automatically
>   populated with intelligent defaults to simplify the customization
>   process.

See https://launchpad.net/cubic and many tutorials on internet.

Comment: I used that one too but cubic generated ISO is also not installing if i'm removing any one of the packages, else it installing fine.

Comment: This is the official guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization but it uses the UCK (Ubuntu Customization Kit) and the project is discontinued....

Comment: Thank you, and what do you mean by dicontinued?

Comment: @K.venkatesh discontinued means there is no further development of the project, no new updates or versions, no error solving anymore, maybe not compatible anymore with new versions of other software...

Comment: @ponsfrilus (this is not related to this post) - I noticed several edit suggestions from you with adding [tag:18.04]. Please only add a tag when it is really relevant for the question.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu itself has at least two ways to achieve what you want without using 3rd party tools:

## [Ubuntu Minimal Installation](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/02/ubuntu-18-04-minimal-install-option)

Ubuntu now have a "minimal installation" option included in its installer. It installs the basic utilities (desktop environment, web browser, etc) leaving out packages such as LibreOffice, Thunderbird and Transmission.

## [Ubuntu MinimalCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD)

Ubuntu also offers a minimal ISO (only 64 MB!) which let you fully customize your system. Please note that this option may be a bit advanced for begginers.

---

You can also take a look at some non-Ubuntu options:

## [Arch Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Linux)

A rolling-release Linux distribution whose default installation is a minimal base system. It is targeted at the proficient GNU/Linux user, or anyone with a do-it-yourself attitude who is willing to read the documentation, and solve their own problems.

## [Gentoo Linux](https://www.gentoo.org/get-started/about/)

A metadistribution known by its extreme configurability and adaptability. Packages are usually compiled to be optimized as much as the user wants.

## [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/)

Project that provides you with step-by-step instructions for building your own custom Linux system, entirely from source code. Although it is usually used for educational purposes, you can use the system you build on a daily basis.